# react-redux: `state.get` is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have reducers like below:

```
// SignIn.js
const signIn = (state = {
  mobilePhone: {
    signInWay: 'email',
    countryCallingCode: '+65'
  }
}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SIGN_IN':
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.signInForm);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default signIn;

// UserInput.js
const userInput = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'USER_INPUT':
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.kv);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default userInput;

// Then index.js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import userInput from './UserInput';
import signIn from './SignIn';

const gateApp = combineReducers({
  userInput,
  signInForm: signIn
});

export default gateApp;
```

Then in the `mapStateToProps`, when I tried to do

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state)
  return {
    signInForm: state.get('signInForm')
  };
};
```

I got error: `SignIn.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: state.get is not a function`, and I logged out the state object, it gave me something like this:

[image]

Where was going wrong?

Comment: Could you try using `state.signInForm`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you're using a library like ImmutableJS, the `state` is just an normal JavaScript object - there's no `get` method to call on it. You should just access the data through dot notation:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log(state)
  return {
    signInForm: state.signInForm
  };
};
```

Comment: oh, oh, thank you very much, I thought the `connect` will play some magics on it, haha...

Comment: and what if using ImmutableJS - I have this error trying to enable persistance within react-boilerplate

Answer (score 1):

It should looks like this `state.signInForm` not `state.get('signInForm')`